# Multiple Sets in MDX using WITH function

Tags: mdx, with-statement

Starting to learn MDX as one of the databases at work is based around a Cube
I have an SQL background so worked my way round understanding Tuples and Sets.

Where I am getting stuck is if I wanted to define multiple sets how can I do this via the WITH function. Following function works fine when I am defining one set with WITH function but surely there must be a way to define multiple sets.

Apologies if very basic function, I did try the search box but perhaps wasn't phrasing the request correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help

```
WITH SET 
[MARKET] AS {[Location].&[Australia],[Location].[Singapore]},
[CALENDAR] AS {[Calendar].&[April,2018],[Calendar].&[May,2018]}

SELECT    
{([Measures].[Money]),([Measures].[Target])} on 0,

{([CALENDAR],[MARKET],[Sales Department])}on 1

FROM AussieDatabase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define each set explicitly, they can then be cross joined on rows

```
WITH 
    SET [MARKET] AS 
         {[Location].&[Australia]
         ,[Location].[Singapore]},
    SET [CALENDAR] AS 
         {[Calendar].&[April,2018]
         ,[Calendar].&[May,2018]}

SELECT    
{
    [Measures].[Money]
   ,[Measures].[Target]
 } on 0,

[CALENDAR] * [MARKET] on 1

FROM AussieDatabase;
```

Comment: Thanks! Rookie mistake. (Hands over face). Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: No problem, it looks like sql and smells like sql but it’s quite different